# How to put Output textfile of Java program to kibana-logstash-elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am having a java application that will do some actions and saves the corresponding time duration in a textfile.Is there any way to integrate this textfile data to display in kibana.

How to configure logstash and elasticsearch for this.I am new to this area. Can you suggest some basic tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this [tutorial](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash)

Try using Grok input type **"file"** to read log data from the textfile described [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/file)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Kibana website where there are tutorials, examples, etc, on how you can use that framework to organise your logs.